# Scala - How is a variable of type Any stored in memory?

Tags: scala, types

How is it possible to create variable of type Any?
And why does isInstanceOf[Int] print true?
I declared x to be Any, not Int.

How does it work? What is happening behind the scenes?

```
val x = 4: Any // OK

x.isInstanceOf[Int] // true
x.isInstanceOf[String] // false
```

**[EDIT]** Maybe to rephrase my question:
How does `val x = 4: Any` look like in memory?
And once it is stored in memory as `Any` type, how can I later say that this particular blob of bytes is `Int`, but not say `String`?

Does it come along with some kind of information what was the "original" type? Here for example if I typed `4` **AND LATER** said this is `Any` type, would it store this original type of 4 as an `Int`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What *exactly* do you mean by "How is it possible to create variable of type Any"? You declare a variable to be of type `Any`, just like you declare a variable of any other type, there's nothing special about `Any`, it's just a type like any other type. In fact, you already did that in your code! "And why does isInstanceOf[Int] print true?" – Because `4` is an instance of `Int`.

Comment: I rephrased my question.

Answer (score 5):

Scala language is defined to support the notion of inheritance polymorphism. In other words, if there is some type T which inherits from type U, then any value of type T can be assigned to a variable of type U:

```
class T extends U
val x: U = new T // compiles
```

Same thing with `Any` and `Int`: in Scala, `Int` inherits from `Any`, therefore it is possible to store an integer in an `Any` variable:

```
val x: Any = 4  // essentially the same as your example
```

Also, all of the runtimes Scala runs on know what type of value is *actually* stored in a variable, regardless of the static type of this variable. This is important for many features of the language, in particular, virtual method overrides, but it also allows you to do manual checks and downcasts, which is what your code does (the checks). In  other words, the `isInstanceOf` method checks the *runtime* type of a value stored in a variable, not the static type known at the compile time (which would be quite pointless).

Comment: I like how in Scala, `any` is abstract. I've always felt that C#'s object should _conceptually_ be abstract.